# Truffle/npm error "Expected parameter 'from' not passed to function"

Tags: blockchain, truffle, npm-start

I am playing with Truffle and while building, I am getting the following error. I searched internet but found nothing useful.

While running the "truffle.cmd deploy" command.

> C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-expect\index.js:3
>       expected_keys.forEach(function(key) { ^ Error: Expected parameter 'from' not passed to function.
>       at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-expect\index.js:5:1
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object.options (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-expect\index.js:3:1)
>       at Object.run (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-migrate\index.js:122:1)
>       at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-core\lib\commands\migrate.js:79:1
>       at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-migrate\index.js:291:1
>       at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-migrate\index.js:115:1
>       at done (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-migrate\~\node-dir\lib\paths.js:61:1)
>       at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-migrate\~\node-dir\lib\paths.js:118:1
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! tip-and-win@1.0.0 start: `start cmd /K
>   ganache-cli --deterministic && truffle.cmd deploy && cd app && npm
>   install && npm run start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the tip-and-win@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above. npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules
>   missing, did you mean to install?

Answer (score 0):

Your current provider did not have any account. so, first you need to create an account on your rpc network by personal.newAccount(); after that run truffle migrate.
Hope this will help you to resolve this issue.